# yii2 editable internal server error

Tags: yii2, x-editable, internal-server-error

I have Gangguan model, I have id_registrasi (not a PK) in Gangguan model, 
I want to edit id_registrasi in my gridView using editable, the pop up windows give an error message "Internal Server Error" but when I refresh page  (F5), the column has successful changed.
and the problem is i cant handle that error. ..
this is my controller

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')){
        $Id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
        $model1 = $this->findModel($Id);
        $posted = current($_POST['Gangguan']);
            $model1->id_registrasi = $posted['id_registrasi'];
            $model1->save(false);
          $output =  $model1->id_registrasi;
         $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']); 
       echo $out;
         return;
}
```

and this is the column

```
[
'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
'attribute'=>'id_registrasi',
'hAlign' => 'top',
'vAlign' => 'middle',
'width'=>'100px',
'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-sticky-column'],
'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-sticky-column'],
          'footerOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-sticky-column'],
'pageSummary' => true,
],
```

Comment: 1.First you should enable debug mode: Yii defines and uses the constants YII_DEBUG and YII_ENV. And they are set to 'true' and 'dev'. This is because the basic app template has prepared it this way in the [index.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/web/index.php) file. This file tells us also that we should remove those lines for production mode, i.e. on the production machine. Then those constants are set to 'false' and 'prod' by default.([More information can be found on Defining Constants and Environment Constants](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your controller and it should be ok then.

```
use yii\helpers\json;
```